# Is this a good way to have class level member variables?

Tags: objective-c, static, class-design

I'm trying to violate the laws of objective C a little by having static (class level) variables that have setters and getters:

```
+(CGRect*)defaultOpFr:(CGRect*)set{
    static CGRect * defaultOpFr = nil;

    if (set) {
        if (!defaultOpFr) {
            defaultOpFr = malloc(sizeof(defaultOpFr));
        }
        defaultOpFr->size.width = set->size.width;
        defaultOpFr->size.height = set->size.height;
        defaultOpFr->origin.x = set->origin.x;
        defaultOpFr->origin.y = set->origin.y;
    }
    return defaultOpFr;
}
```

It seems to work, but I'm wondering if there's a better way. The idea is to call it with nil to retrieve the value, call it with a CGRect to set a new value.

Comment: There are no "member" variables in Objective-C.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yup;  that'll work, but be completely against any kind of common pattern.

Why don't you simply have a standard setter/getter pair?  Even at the class level, that is fine:

```
static CGRect barf;
+ (CGRect) barf { return barf; }
+ (void) setBarf:(CGRect)aRect { barf = aRect; }
```

Done.

Comment: And even more perversely, by following proper naming conventions, you can technically do `CGRect r = MyClass.barf;` and `MyClass.barf = r;`.  Not that you ever *should* (because dot syntax is an abomination that defiles the beautiful sea of square brackets, etc etc), but you could...

Comment: Yup;  though some compilers will have a bit of a nervous tic when compiling a dot expression with a Class receiver....

Comment: I can't declare `static CGRect barf;` outside of a function though, I tried putting it with the member variables and just next to the function declarations. How do I get a static variable that is in scope for both functions? I like yours better but I can't make it work.

Comment: oh I take that back, I had to paste it in the implementation.

Comment: The variable declaration could go anywhere in the .m file, as long as it is before the uses of it (and isn't in a method, func, or @interface).  No difference.  There are no member variables in objc. If you mean that you put it next to the instance variables, yes, that will not work because that would be in the scope of an @interface.

Comment: Hang on, I'm not having any success with this, the value won't stay set, I tried a very simple true/false test, initialize it false, if false print false and set true, if true print true and set false, and it's always coming up false. I put it in the @implementation and again before the @implementation, no dice yet.